# Warning while updating(bad component version) latest dependency versions in maven from nexus

Tags: maven, versioning, nexus

Is any possibility to ignore the known bad version component while using maven use latest dependency versions?

Example: There are 3 components
Component 1
Component 2
Component 3

Component 2 and 3 has a dependency Component 1.

Component 2 has updated to latest version of Component 1. Then, they figured out some problem with new Component 1 version

How can we ignore the bad component 1 version to not propagate into Component 3.
Is it possible to set any flags in nexus? so it gives a warning when maven tries to update the latest broken version?

Answer (score 0):

The Sonatype Nexus Professional CLM edition allows you to set up policies like that and use them in a staging release flow.

Beyond that you have Sonatype CLM itself which can be used to use those policies and also expose them in Eclipse, Hudson, Jenkins, Bamboo, Sonarqube and command line tools.

Apart from that you can also make hacks with the Maven Enforcer plugin but in my experience that is very cumbersome and does not really scale.

Comment: We are not using CLM edition. We just have nexus pro edition. Is it sufficient if we have nexus pro?